# Error 503 Service Unavailable on Varnish, but varnishlog shows no error

Tags: nginx, varnish

I have a server running Varnish and nginx. The frontend website reports a 503 error:

> Error 503 Service Unavailable
>
> Service Unavailable
>
> Guru Meditation:
> XID: 317911182
>
> Varnish cache server

This is the content of `/etc/varnish/foo.vcl`:

```
backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8080";
  .connect_timeout = 1s;
  .first_byte_timeout = 90s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 90s;
}
```

`varnishlog` apparently shows no issue:

```
0 CLI          - Rd ping
0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1486463718 1.0
0 CLI          - Rd ping
0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1486463721 1.0
0 CLI          - Rd ping
0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1486463724 1.0
0 CLI          - Rd ping
0 CLI          - Wr 200 19 PONG 1486463727 1.0
```

However, there is no service running on port 8080 on localhost:

```
server# netstat -anp | grep 8080
server# telnet localhost 8080
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

and in fact the nginx log reports an error while trying to connect to it:

```
2017/02/07 11:51:11 [error] 2008#0: *188 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.2.3.4, server: _, request: "GET /mydir/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/mydir/", host: "myhost.example.com"
```

What could I check to further troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: What service you're expecting to have running on port 8080?

Comment: It should be SAP Hybris on Tomcat.

Comment: So is your Tomcat running on localhost on port 8080? If not, I don't think this is Varnish problem.

Comment: Apparently not. How come then `varnishlog` doesn't return an error? Does it just ping the server without probing the port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following lines show normal operation - Varnish is checking if it's caches are ok. This is normal and not related to connectivity to backend.

```
     0 CLI            - Rd ping
     0 CLI            - Wr 200 19 PONG 1486473078 1.0
```

If the backend has configured health check, you would be seeing something similar to this:

varnishlog output:

```
     0 CLI            - Rd ping
     0 CLI            - Wr 200 19 PONG 1486473075 1.0
     0 Backend_health - boot.default Still sick ------- 1 3 3 0.000000 0.000000
     0 Backend_health - boot.default Still sick ------- 0 3 3 0.000000 0.000000
```

or

```
 32771 Timestamp      b Start: 1486473576.634500 0.000000 0.000000
 32771 BereqMethod    b GET
 32771 BereqURL       b /
 32771 BereqProtocol  b HTTP/1.1
 32771 BereqHeader    b Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
 32771 BereqHeader    b User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
 32771 BereqHeader    b Accept: */*
 32771 BereqHeader    b X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
 32771 BereqHeader    b Accept-Encoding: gzip
 32771 BereqHeader    b X-Varnish: 32771
 32771 VCL_call       b BACKEND_FETCH
 32771 VCL_return     b fetch
 32771 FetchError     b no backend connection
```

default.vlc:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8081";
    .probe = {
        .url = "/status";
        .timeout = 60 ms;
        .interval = 10s;
        .window = 3;
        .threshold = 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem turned out to be probably a failed DB access which prevented Tomcat to launch SAP Hybris. I'm marking your answer as accepted because it clarified some issues I had with `varnishlog`, and no further answer is needed (at least at the moment).